# Rails - Proper way to select and submit from a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and am trying to figure out the proper way to do this, but am having trouble finding an answer on Google. In my app, the user performs a search, which queries a 3rd party API and then displays a list of results for the user to choose from. When the user clicks the "Add" button for the result they want, I pass a hidden_field_tag that contains the API's ID to my controller and create a record in the database.

My questions are: Should I have a form for each result like my code below? Or should I use the link_to helper instead? Is there a better way?

Thanks.

My current code:

```
<% @series.each do |series| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <%= form_tag({controller: "series", action: "create"}, method: "post") do %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag(:series_id, series.xpath('seriesid').text) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
   <%= series.xpath('seriesname').text %>
   <% end %>
  </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use link to with post http method. For e.g.

```
link_to "Add", series_path(series_id: series.xpath('seriesid').text), method: post
```

(Change the param name and action to suit your  need.)

Rails has js component converts this into a form submit automatically.